# Cannot cancel a group transition in Corona to avoid memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, coronasdk, transition

My code looks something like this:

```
local myTransition
local myGroup = display.newGroup()

-- Fill group with all sorts of stuff

-- Create the transition
myTransition = transition.to(myGroup, {alpha = 1})

-- Get rid of the transition
if myTransition ~= nil then
    transition.cancel(myTransition)
end

myTransition = nil
```

When I try I get nil value:

```
Runtime error
?:0: attempt to index a nil value
stack traceback:
[C]:?
?: in function 'cancel'
```

If I want to cancel any other transition of any other object, works great. When I try on group transition it fails.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call transition as:

```
myTransition = transition.to(myGroup, {time = 1000, alpha = 1})
```

and cancellation as:

```
if myTransition ~= nil then
    transition.cancel(myTransition)
    myTransition = nil
end
```

Keep Coding................ :)

Comment: Yep, that was it, I had to nullify it inside the if statement. I'm so dump :(